# Properly set Repeat/Shuffle option in MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm working on a simple audio streaming app based on the [Media app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview) architecture from official Android documentation:

[image: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/images/audio-activity-and-service.png]

By using the **MediaControllerCompat** I'm trying to achieve the Repeat/Shuffle controls. But most of the options aren't working. E.g:

The following code enables shuffling:

```
getTransportControls().setShuffleMode(PlaybackStateCompat.SHUFFLE_MODE_ALL);
```

But if I set the mode to none the player is still shuffling and has no effect for cancelation.

```
getTransportControls().setShuffleMode(PlaybackStateCompat.SHUFFLE_MODE_NONE);
```

Also the single/all repeat option isn't working

```
getTransportControls().setRepeatMode(PlaybackStateCompat.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);

getTransportControls().setRepeatMode(PlaybackStateCompat.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You need to tell how you connect the MediaSession with your media player. The controller is just the abstraction. Are you using MediaSessionConnector of the ExoPlayer library?

Comment: @marcbaechinger Would you mind having a look here? [Github Repo](https://github.com/mitchtabian/Spotify-Clone/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/codingwithmitch/audiostreamer)

Comment: Please describe it here on SOF, so everyone can participate.